# How to use getOrCreate() method in SparkContext class and what exactly is the functionality we achieve from this method

Tags: apache-spark

What is the use of `getOrCreate()` method in `SparkContext Class` and how I can use it? I did not found any suitable example(coding wise) for this.

What I understand is that using above method I can share spark context between applications. What do we mean by applications here?
Is application a different job submitted to a spark cluster?
If so then we should be able to use global variables(broadcast) and temp tables registered in one application into another application ?

Please if anyone can elaborate and give suitable example on this.

Answer (score 4):

As given in the [Javadoc for SparkContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#getOrCreate()), getOrCreate() is useful when applications may wish to share a SparkContext. So yes, you can use it to share a SparkContext object across Applications. And yes, you can re-use broadcast variables and temp tables across.

As for understanding Spark Applications, please refer this [link](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_spark_apps.html). In short, an application is the highest-level unit of computation in Spark. And what you submit to a spark cluster is not a job, but an application. Invoking an action inside a Spark application triggers the launch of a **job** to fulfill it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I could understand from your explaination getOrCreate() method somehow creates a global singleton context and if   getOrCreate() method is invoked in different applications running on same spark cluster I will get the same instance of spark context?
And if this is true I can share state of RDD's(Global variables and temp tables) created in these applications with each other as spark context is same ? And all this I am able to achieve even though these applications are running on different JVM within same spark cluster? I hope I understood this correctly!!

Comment: You can share a SparkContext only within a single JVM (The JVM in which the Spark Driver is running). So, sharing of SparkContext only happens between applications running within the same Driver JVM. Within the same JVM, getOrCreate() will give you the same instance of SparkContext; and this will help you share broadcast variables, etc among different applications spawned by the same Spark Driver.

Comment: Now I understood what you are trying to explain. Is there any suitable example on how to spawn different applications from a spark driver running on a JVM ? .  As if I try to run different applications on a spark cluster it will always run different driver processes for each application on different JVM.  I tried to find it but could not get any suitable example.

Answer (score 1):

getOrCreate

public SparkSession getOrCreate()

Gets an existing SparkSession or, if there is no existing one, creates a new one based on the options set in this builder.
This method first checks whether there is a valid thread-local SparkSession and if yes, return that one. It then checks whether there is a valid global default SparkSession and if yes, return that one. If no valid global default SparkSession exists, the method creates a new SparkSession and assigns the newly created SparkSession as the global default.

In case an existing SparkSession is returned, the config options specified in this builder will be applied to the existing SparkSession.

Please check link: [https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.Builder.html][1]

An example can be :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()
```